# how to write custom validator for reactive form control

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I want to validate a field `type` to contain the repeating selected elements in an Array form `itemsFormArray`. I wrote a custom validator for this (`itemTypeValidator`), but error message isn't displayed. Also, I wrote a custom `TypeItemErrorMatcher` class that implements from `ErrorStateMatcher`, but it doesn’t work out (
that is, if the debug function `isErrorState`, then the breakpoint does'nt stop at that place). where is the mistake?

`item.component.html`

```html
    <div *ngFor="let item of itemsFormArray.controls; let i = index">
  <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
    <mat-select [value]="item.value.type" (selectionChange)="selectItemType($event, i)" [errorStateMatcher]="typeItemErrorMatcher">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let itemType of itemTypes$ | async" [value]="itemType.code">
        {{itemType.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="itemsFormArray.controls[i].get('type').hasError('itemTypeExisted')">Уже существует</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

`item.component.ts`

```js
typeItemErrorMatcher = new TypeItemErrorMatcher();
```

`form.service.ts`

```js
createItemsGroup(value: any): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    type: [value.type, this.itemTypeValidator()]
  });
}

itemTypeValidator(): ValidatorFn {

  return (itemTypeControl: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
    const itemsFormArray = itemTypeControl.root.value.itemsContent;
    if (itemsFormArray && itemTypeControl.value.length !== 0) {
      const resultConditionItemType = itemsFormArray.items.some(item => {
        return itemTypeControl.value === item.type;
      });
      return resultConditionItemType ? {itemTypeExisted: true} : null;;
    }
  };
}
```

`typeItemErrorMatcher.ts`

```js
export class TypeItemErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {

 isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
  return form.hasError('itemTypeExisted');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="myFormField.get('value').hasError(patternCustom)">required field</mat-error>
```

Comment: Сan you help me? I have a new question about form validation